# Will Background tab repaint when out of focus

Tags: javascript, browser, rendering, repaint, throttling

Let's say I have two tabs, in  tab1 react content is rendered and based on some condition tab switch occurs now I'm moved  to tab 2  now on some other conditions the  tab one is re rendered with entire different content so will  the tab1 be repainted  when it is out of focus , I can see all the re rendering happening  when I switch the tab back to tab1 (all at once).not sure if this is related to browser throttling. Is there a way to force repaint of background tabs

Comment: React will repaint if any state data changes happen, you should provide your code to get better answer.

Comment: Ideally it should,  will it still  do it  if it is present in background tab ,sorry can't provide code for this .